# How can I speed up this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me with this query? It's working fine but it take too much time. I determined the problem was too many OR statements in `tb_activities`. Does anyone have any ideas to make this query faster?

```
SELECT tb_posts.*
FROM   tb_posts
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT c_id
               FROM   tb_users
               WHERE  tb_posts.c_uid = tb_users.c_id
                      AND tb_users.c_tokens > 0)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT c_id
                       FROM   tb_activities
                       WHERE  tb_posts.c_url = tb_activities.c_url
                              AND tb_activities.c_category = 'gplus'
                              AND ( tb_activities.c_uid LIKE '%,6x1,%'
                                     OR tb_activities.c_uid LIKE '%,6x1'
                                     OR tb_activities.c_uid LIKE '6x1,%'
                                     OR tb_activities.c_uid = '6x1' ))
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT c_id
                       FROM   tb_blacklist
                       WHERE  tb_posts.c_url LIKE Concat('%', tb_blacklist.c_url
                                                  , '%')
                              AND tb_blacklist.c_times > 2
                              AND tb_blacklist.c_category = 'gplus')
       AND tb_posts.c_category = 'classic'
       AND tb_posts.c_status = 'run'
       AND tb_posts.c_nogplus = 0
GROUP  BY tb_posts.c_url
ORDER  BY tb_posts.c_cost DESC,
          tb_posts.c_date DESC
LIMIT  30
```

Comment: indexes... all im saying

Answer (score 1):

What I did here is rewriting the first `WHERE EXISTS ...`. Why? [Here](http://solutionfactor.net/blog/2011/11/06/mysql-inner-join-vs-exists-may-yield-better-performance/) is the answer. Another interesting read is [this](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). So you might consider rewriting the query further. Unfortunately I don't have any more time now. But the **main performance boost** you will get anyway **by adding (compound) indexes**. Put indexes on columns on which `JOIN`s are based or columns which are often used in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT tb_posts.*
FROM   tb_posts
INNER JOIN tb_users ON tb_posts.c_uid = tb_users.c_id
WHERE  tb_users.c_tokens > 0
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT c_id
                       FROM   tb_activities
                       WHERE  tb_posts.c_url = tb_activities.c_url
                              AND tb_activities.c_category = 'gplus'
                              AND ( tb_activities.c_uid LIKE '%,6x1,%'
                                     OR tb_activities.c_uid LIKE '%,6x1'
                                     OR tb_activities.c_uid LIKE '6x1,%'
                                     OR tb_activities.c_uid = '6x1' ))
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT c_id
                       FROM   tb_blacklist
                       WHERE  tb_posts.c_url LIKE Concat('%', tb_blacklist.c_url, '%')
                              AND tb_blacklist.c_times > 2
                              AND tb_blacklist.c_category = 'gplus')
       AND tb_posts.c_category = 'classic'
       AND tb_posts.c_status = 'run'
       AND tb_posts.c_nogplus = 0
GROUP  BY tb_posts.c_url
ORDER  BY tb_posts.c_cost DESC,
          tb_posts.c_date DESC
LIMIT  30
```

Also you might want to read about [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html), so you know which indexes are used (or not used).

And as a sidenote, Peter Kiss´ tip about changing the order of the `WHERE` clause is nonsense. The query optimizer handles this anyway.